# List of Users in a Role

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, user-roles

with this code I could see on my page list of all users

```
@foreach (MembershipUser user in Membership.GetAllUsers())
{
   @user.UserName
}

var model = Membership.GetAllUsers().Cast<MembershipUser>().Select(x => x.UserName);
return View(model)
```

How do I view a list of users in a role?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string[] usersInRole = Roles.GetUsersInRole("role name");
MembershipUserCollection users = new MembershipUserCollection();

foreach (string userName in usersInRole)
{
        users.Add(Membership.GetUser(userName));
}
```

Comment: i copy your code but in foreach userinrole isn't decalred...i i need put string[] usersInRole = Roles.GetUsersInRole("role name");
 in the view?

Comment: if you just need username, `Roles.GetUsersInRole("role name")` will provide all the users in the role. if you need to access all user details `users` collection containing the details. and remember this code is in your controller. but if you want you can directly put in the model(not recommended)

Comment: for example, to retrieve user details should I just run a linq query in my controller with your code? thanks

Comment: `@foreach (string userName in Roles.GetUsersInRole("role name"))
{
   @userName 
}` try this code for now and you will understand the above code when you get clear idea about MVC

Comment: i received this exception Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server due to a failure in starting the process for the user instance. The connection will be closed.

Comment: I realized, I did some testing. But for example I do not want to display only the name, but also the email etc ... how can I do?

Comment: i solved http://forums.asp.net/p/1776358/4862295.aspx/1?p=True&t=634663986105365732

Comment: @MirkoPastorelli: same thing is there.in your model you can add a property for users. then set it using above users collection. you can access that in the view. remember it is not recommended to use any business logic inside the view.

Answer (score 0):

```
Roles.GetUsersInRole(...)
```

basically, anything regarding roles is a responsibility of a role provider.